# Performing a Javascript function on a django form before adding to database

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have created a template in `Django` that makes a form based on a model. When the `form` is submitted currently the data that was previously in the password field of the form is placed into the `database` rather than the changed value that is included in the "id_Password" field once the `onclick` action is performed. What I want is the `JavaScript` to perform its `function`, then the form is submitted with the data that is on the field once the `function` has been performed.

Can anyone provide any insight?

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}

<h2> To add an account to your wallet fill in the form below and click "Add account to wallet" </h2>

<h3>Load your encryption file</h3>
<input type="file" id="input">
<form action="/yourwallet/addpassword/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ricmoo/aes-js/e27b99df/index.js"></script>
    <ul>
    {{form}}
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add account to wallet" onclick="handleFiles()">
    <input type="button" name="test" value="test" onclick="handleFiles()">

    <script>

        function handleFiles() {
            var file = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsText(file);
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var key = reader.result;
                var element = document.getElementById("id_Password")
                var password = element.value;
                var key_256 = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(key)
                var textBytes = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(password);
                var aesCtr = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ctr(key_256);
                var encryptedBytes = aesCtr.encrypt(textBytes);
                var encryptedHex = aesjs.utils.hex.fromBytes(encryptedBytes);
                element.value = encryptedHex;   
            };
        }

    </script>

</form>

<p> Click <a href="/yourwallet/"> here </a> to return to your wallet. </p>
</body> 
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would look into is JS decorator pattern.  Decorators are very powerful and you would not really need to change much.

http://javascript.info/tutorial/decorators

Answer (score 0):

You must not do this in Javascript. Any half-competent hacker can ignore or change the code that runs in JS. All validation must happen on the backend.

Luckily, Django already has a comprehensive framework for setting and hashing passwords.

Comment: I'm not hashing passwords here, I'm creating a password wallet for my university project and i want to perform all encryption client side to avoid sending the key.